# Visual Studio 2013 libgit2 error

Tags: github, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to set up git with VS2013 by following these instructions:

[How do I add an existing Solution to GitHub from Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982053/how-do-i-add-an-existing-solution-to-github-from-visual-studio-2013)

However in `Home | Unsynced Commits`, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Unknown (Error).
No error message has been provided by the native library
```

Considering that the error message is very unclear, I don't know where to start troubleshooting.

**EDIT**: The error occurs not only with `Unsynced Commits`, but with `Changes` and `Branches` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20004092/3286583

I was also getting the libgit2 error. It was an issue because of "Initialize this repository with a README.md".

For removing the solution from source control, close Visual Studio and delete the .gitattributes, .gitignore and ".git" folder. Now reopen the solution and try again with above mentioned answer's method.