# Is there a way to show the Git commands that Visual Studio executes?

Tags: git, visual-studio

In Visual Studio Code, there is a "Show Git Output" menu item that shows the recent Git commands that have been run. For an example of what this looks like, see [3:35+ in this video](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/versioncontrol).

Is there a way to do the same in Visual Studio?

Comment: Wouldn't a basic Git tutorial be more useful?

Comment: Maybe, but for example the Git tools in VS have Sync option, this operation does not exist on Git. This operation as I know execute two commands Git Pull and git push, one after other. The maybe some other cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038999/differences-between-commit-commit-and-push-commit-and-sync says "Commit and Sync does three things. First, it will commit. Second, it will perform a pull (grabs the updated information from the remote repo). Finally, it will push." It's just a series of commands that MS gave a name to.

Comment: Other example for instance  is what command does VS pass to Git when you move a file to other folder in the solution explorer and then commits changes? and so on

Comment: Again, a basic Git tutorial would answer all these questions. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv for moving files, followed by a https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit to commit the change.

Comment: you are making my point. Which parameter uses VS to accomplish this from all of them? I know how to do it I know the git basics. The question is not how to do it, but which command uses VS and if there is a way to intercept them. I think VS Code has that functionality

Comment: It's not using a special magic parameter. It's doing three basic Git operations in sequence. Just like if you build a batch file, or run them manually from the command line.

Comment: @foluis You might be looking for something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166568.aspx and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/aa62e92f-5573-420f-b03c-a7016624edf3/how-to-intercept-the-visual-studio-command-execution-event-of-project-buildrebuild?forum=vsx) might be useful as well.

Comment: Please note that Git is version control software, and GitHub is an online web service that uses Git; they are not the same thing.  I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to remove the [tag:github] tag.  In addition, it is best to not have your question rely on external sources, so I added a description so that your question will remain understandable even without the video you linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not entirely possible (for instance, for VS2015) because:

- only [Visual Studio 15 Preview 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40059664/6309) is switching from using **[libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/)** to using git commands directly.
- As explained in "[Work from the Git command prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/dd286572)", VS2015 does not know how to perform *all* Git commands anyway