# Add an existing (GitHub) C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 (without solution file)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I would like to add an existing C++ GitHub project to Visual Studio. I already know [how to how do I add an existing **Solution** to GitHub from Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19982053/3848809). Here is my procedure

1. In Visual Studio 2013
2. I go to Team explorer tab / Connect to team project / Clone
3. In the clone dialog I enter my https GitHub link and my local repository path
4. I click on Clone button

After that I don't know what to do. The problem is I don't have a solution file. I have my idea: I need to to create a new solution file, then project, then add manually each cpp file in my new solution and project. This sound so heavy I'm asking if there is a better and faster procedure. Perhaps I don't need a solution file.

Note: I already did C++ coding but I never used Visual Studio as my main C++ editor. The project I try to integrate to my Visual Studio 2013 is https://github.com/Ryochan7/antimicro

Comment: just create an empty solution and add the project to it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [CMake](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/) to create the solution file. A lot of C++ projects on the web will mention this in their Readme files. Alternatively, you can create a new project (which will create a solution) and copy the code into it.