# How do I add an existing VS 2013 code to GitHub through Visual Studio 2013

Tags: github

I have an existing solution in Visual Studio 2013, how do I export it to GitHub?

I referred this link :
[How do I add an existing Solution to GitHub from Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982053/how-do-i-add-an-existing-solution-to-github-from-visual-studio-2013)

UPDATE:
I am unable to understand below points which is from above link:

1. Surf to GitHub
2. Create a new repository DO NOT SELECT Initialize this repository with a README. That creates an empty repository with no Master branch.
3. Once created open the repository and copy the URL (it's on the right of the screen in the current version).

Comment: Sella, you just need to go to [github.com](http://github.com/) to create the repository (create an account). Those steps are not performed in Visual Studio: you just need the URL of the repository to paste in VS after you create it there.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.I am using below link to upload my project into github.Thats working fine.
http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step/
Thanks
Sella.