# How do I Export an existing Solution to GitHub from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, github-for-windows

I am strucking an issue in exporting an existing solution to GitHub from Visual Studio 2013. I referred the following link , but 3 rd point onwards am not understanding.the following are the link :
[How do I add an existing Solution to GitHub from Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982053/how-do-i-add-an-existing-solution-to-github-from-visual-studio-2013).

Please, can any one suggest me to push my code into github with briefly or share me the links regarding this.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, please post the question to the author there itself here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982053/how-do-i-add-an-existing-solution-to-github-from-visual-studio-2013. You can also refer to the following url - http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step/. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks michael , this will helps me

Comment: Thanks kinshuk4, this will helps me.

Comment: Great thanks Kinshuk4, this link works for me
http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step/

Comment: My pleasure Sandeep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure **Microsoft Git Provider** is selected in Visual Studio's **Options / Source Control**.