# "Add Solution to Source Control ... " doesn't work

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2013

**I am stuck with the step,**

> 5. Enter the GitHub URL into the yellow box (use HTTPS URL, not the default shown SSH one)

[image]

I don't even see any input field. Only the following error message.

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. 
Category = Unknown (Error). 
No error message has been provided by the native library
```

This error is generated just when I click "Unsynched Commits".

.

I am following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20004092/159072),

> OK this worked for me.
>
> 1. Open the solution in Visual Studio 2013
> 2. Select File | Add to Source Control
> 3. Select the Microsoft Git Provider
>
> That creates a local GIT repository
>
> 3. Surf to GitHub
> 4. Create a new repository DO NOT SELECT Initialize this repository with a README
>
> That creates an empty repository with no Master branch
>
> 1. Once created open the repository and copy the URL (it's on the right of the screen in the current version)
> 2. Go back to Visual Studio
>
>    - Make sure you have the Microsoft Git Provider selected under Tools/Options/Source Control/Plug-in Selection
> 3. Open Team Explorer
> 4. Select Home | Unsynced Commits
> 5. Enter the GitHub URL into the yellow box (use HTTPS URL, not the default shown SSH one)
> 6. Click Publish
> 7. Select Home | Changes
> 8. Add a Commit comment
> 9. Select Commit and Push from the drop down
>
> Your solution is now in GitHub

.

Comment: What are you entering into the field?

Comment: @GlenPierce, i don't even see any field.

Comment: @GlenPierce, this error is generated just when I click "Unsynched Commits".

Comment: ok, well I've never used the plugin you mention, but I'm going to try to help a bit here... Is the repo initialized locally already?

Comment: @GlenPierce, (1) I am using built-in VS2013 plugin. (2) I am following the exact given steps. So, I think when I clicked "Add To Source Control ...", the solution should have been added to the local repository. But, that isn't the case.

Comment: I'd try to add it via the command line.

Comment: I never faced this problem. Which version of git have you install?

Comment: @MatheusValienteSouza, I am not using any external git driver. I am using Microsoft's Git provider.